# Is it safe to install newer Python and Git versions from source?

Tags: git, python, linux-mint, make

I wanted to install newer versions of Python and Git to my system.  I eventually used the commands below to compile and install new versions.  However, I was informed that it would have been better to use `make altinstall` for Python.  What is wrong with installing new versions the way I did?

Install Python from source:

```
mkdir ~/getpython; cd ~/getpython
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.4.2/Python-3.4.2.tgz
tar -xvf Python-3.4.2.tgz
cd Python-3.4.2.tgz
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev openssl
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Install Git from source:

```
mkdir ~/getgit; cd ~/getgit
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev libexpat1-dev asciidoc xsltproc xmlto docbook2x
git clone https://github.com/git/git
make prefix=/usr all doc info   #note this takes a few minutes
sudo make prefix=/usr install install-doc install-html install-info
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main problem here is that you've overwritten libraries manged by the package manager with your own files.  Other packages and system scripts may (in Python's case *very much do*) depend on these packages, potentially at the given versions/patches.  If you overwrite system libraries, you run the risk of breaking the system.

Python's `altinstall` will avoid some of these problems by not symlinking the default `python` command, but it may not completely avoid stepping on the system still.

If you want to compile newer versions, it may be better to use a different prefix such as `/opt` or the home directory of the user that will run those programs.  Python includes a further mechanism to separate system libraries from application requirements in the form of [virtualenvs](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/).

---

For installing newer Python versions for your personal use (as opposed to setting up a server or multi-user system, I recommend the following steps.  (The first 3 are generally applicable to any package.):

1. `./configure --prefix=$HOME/.local` configure for installation to your home directory
2. `make -j5 && make install` compile with 5 processes, install based on configure prefix
3. Add `export PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"` to the end of your .bashrc file so that the newly installed packages will be on your path.  Start a new terminal after this.  `type python3` will show `python3 is /home/david/.local/bin/python3`.
4. Create a virtualenv when starting a project using the `pyvenv-3.4` script provided by the package.  `$HOME/.local/bin/pyvenv-3.4 /path/to/my_new_venv`.
5. Activate the virtualenv when working on your project: `source /path/to/my_venv/bin/activate`.  Install packages there with pip: `pip install flask`

Comment: So basically, the easiest way is enter a virtualenv first then simple make install without opt prefix?

Comment: @Okuma.Tony no, it only makes sense to use virtualenv *after* you've installed the new Python package.  I've added instructions to get you started.